# Changing from HDD to SSD

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro mid 12 with a 500 GB HDD. For performance purposes I want to upgrade to a SSD. My HDD is nearly full I have used 440 GB with a lot of important business files that I cannot afford to loose. How can I migrate so that I keep everything from my old hard drive to my new SSD. I cannot loose software or files.

Comment: An external time machine backup? A TB drive is cheap enough and if the data is important, good to have. Install the new SSD, then use migration assistant.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways you can do this. I'll cover the two cleanest ways here.

### Restoring the disk from the source or image

This will require that you have simultaneous access to at least two disks.

1. If you can't access the HDD and SSD simultaneously, [Image the HDD to another disk you can access via Disk Utility.](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph5841?locale=en_US)

   1. Boot via [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) (recommended) or an external bootable volume/installer.
   2. Select your HDD in Disk Utility.
   3. Click "Image" in the menu bar (if it's not there, add it by right clicking and dragging it in.)
   4. Save your image to an external volume.
2. Install the SSD.
3. Boot via [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) (recommended) or an external bootable volume/installer.
4. Open Disk Utility.
5. Restore the SSD from the HDD or image of the HDD.

   1. Select your SSD in the sidebar of Disk Utility.
   2. Click "Restore" in the menu bar (if it's not there, add it by right clicking and dragging it in).
   3. Select the proper volume/image.
   4. Restore

### Using Migration Assistant

This will require you have simultaneous access to the two disks from two separate Macs or a Time Machine backup of your HDD.

[Follow the instructions from here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350)

Answer (score 1):

What I'm suggesting I think is an easy solution. You can use Time Machine (if you never used it you can set-up the backup of the entire HDD in an external disk) and with backup tool you automatically save the entire content of your HDD naturally assuming your external disk is large enough.

After this procedure, you can install the new SSD drive(that must have the same dimension of the previous HDD and so 500 GB) in the MacBook and procede with a *restore from external disk* procedure using Time Machine (obtained by press `cmd + R` when you boot the MacBook).

With this procedure you'll change the disk from HDD to SSD and keep all the content of your PC.

Comment: Good expansion of the comment I dropped. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is what I would do, upload ALL your files to iCloud, create a full system backup, this is a great thing to at night, while your sleeping, as it will take some time.

After that has completed. 
Shut your mac down.

Then.
Open up your computer, the hard drive if I remember correctly can be removed easily, but! Make sure to discharge your self from static, remove your battery ribbon, and make sure its away from the board, I like to tape it down to my battery, after that you can now safely remove the HDD, you can install the SSD as long as its obviously Sata, and is certified to work with your machine, reinstall it and screw it down, after that you can re connect the battery, close it all back up and then boot, the CMD button or command, and R hold them both down until you see the computer enter recovery mode, at this point you can let go of the keys, now, click on the bottom option, here we will partition your drive so your mac will work with it, select your drive, from the left sidebar, then go to Erase, in the erase window select the Format dropdown, make sure its selected Mac OS X Extended Journaled, You can name it what ever you want, but for reference I would name it, Mac SSD, the default is Mac HD but you are no longer using a hard drive, but the naming is up to you, give it a bit of time, after that has completed you can go back to the start window, by pressing the close button, the same way you do for closing any other window, the window recovery mode window should reappear, click reinstall OS X, and follow the instructions, after that your mac will shut down and boot up, do not worry we will be replacing all your files from iCloud shortly, follow the normal setup until you get to a point saying I believe setup from iCloud or setup as a new machine or mac, click that and make sure your still on wifi, I recommend ethernet as it will be  LARGE file with it being a full system, enter your iCloud logins it should find the backup, after that the system will do its stuff. you can leave it to do that after its completed your mac will enter into the mac OS X system just like a normal boot up, you will be running Lion, that is the base system used for fresh installs, you can download the updates you did previously from the App store via purchased,

If any thing goes wrong I will Happily help!

Comment: ? iCloud is $10/mo for 1TB.  I'm sure people use it, like it, and get value from it. OP's issue can be solved far better and faster than to upload and then download 400GB. This is the last thing I'd suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Just did this twice last week using Carbon Copy Cloner and a SATA to USB 3.0 Converter cable for SSD/HDD ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00HJZJI84?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJZJI84)).

Attach cable to SSD and Mac. Use CCC to create bootable clone. Open case and swap drives (be careful with the ribbon connector.)